# Может кто дать конструктивный ответ на вопрос такого рода?

Tags: javascript

Can you explain thesis ‘Everthing is an Object in Javascript’?
Можете ли вы объяснить тезис «Все в Javascript является объектом»?

Comment: а примитивы тоже являются объектом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если представить объект как некоторый контейнер, которая внутри себя содержит

1. непосредственно совокупность данных примитивных типов или другие объекты
2. методы для работы с указанными данными

то да, в Javascript все является объектами

например

```
value = 12
```

в том же c++ эти данные будут храниться в памяти или регистре процессора как есть, т.е. для `int value = 12;` будет использован 32 битный регистр или ячейка памяти

а в Javascript это будет некоторый объект с начинкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

причем зачастую прямой доступ непосредственно к самим данными будет скрыт (т.е. как именно реализовано хранение числа 12 из примера будет скрыто от пользователя)

аналогично, если рассмотреть строку:

```
let = 'test';
```

в том же c++ эти данные будут храниться в памяти побайтно (где для каждого символа строки выделен 1 байт), а также в переменной или регистре процессора будет храниться указатель на область памяти, в которой хранится строка (по сути адрес памяти),

а в javasctipt опять хранится обвязка и доступа непосредственно к данным нет (вроде):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

аналогично в javascript дело обстоит с функциями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и любыми другими данными

Comment: Примитивные значения - не объекты. Для них создаётся объект только при операторе доступа к свойствам, и потом объект сразу уничтожается. Примитивы копируются по значению при присвоении в переменные или аргументы. А объекты не копируются. Для них копируется ссылка как примитив.